# What's wrong with this WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

I created web service library like in this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec

To publish it I followed the link http://naztek.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/host-a-wcf-library-in-iis/

but I got this error at run time

> Server Error in '/WCFService1' Application.
>
> The type 'Service', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'Service', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

My `web.config` is :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="test1.Try">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Try" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="test1.Try"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The type 'Service', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in
>   the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.]

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like You missed Step 3 from the second link (about publishing). Especially this part:

> Change the Service attribute value from Service to the fully qualified name of the concrete class in our WCF library, e.g.,  RegistrationServiceLib.RegistrationService

To open svc file use right click -> open with -> XML (text) editor

You should see something like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="YourNamespace.Service" CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs" %>
```

Change this to match your service (just like your tutorial stated).

Comment: could u explain or correct the code for me , I tried to set everything  qualified name

Comment: I extended information in my answer. Show me the inside of your Service.svc file.

Comment: thanks a lot, but it now give error The contract name 'test1.Try' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Try'. any idea how to fix that

Comment: in you web.config you have 'contract="test1.Try"'. This is a place for your contract interface namespace and name. Not your service name.

Comment: Yes. Contract is the interface that your service implements. You need to specify it in your service description in web.config.

Comment: I did but still give The contract name 'test1.ITry' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Try'. also I made sure that both interface and the service class is public

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11474/discussion-between-grzegorz-wilczura-and-amh)

Comment: THANK YOU!  It is a monumental mistake by MS not to include a working WCF example out-of-the-box like they did with asmx Hello World.  For the contracts, I nest them so that one I/F is embedded with a primary I/F.  Otherwise each I/F needs to implement all methods of the other.