# cannot host WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

I created website to host web service when run it raise runtime error

> The contract name 'ITry' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Try'.

My WCF service interface and class look like that

```
namespace test1
{
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface ITry
   {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         UriTemplate = "data/{username}/{password}")]
        string Login(string username, string password);
    }
}
```

Service implementation:

```
namespace test1
{
    public class Try : ITry
    {
        public string Login(string username, string password)
        {
            using (var instance = new FacultySystemEntities1())
            {
                var user = instance.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username && u.UserPassword == password).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user != null)
                    return "true";
                else
                    return "false";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the web site , web.config is look like

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="test1.Try">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Try" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ITry"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with this WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668838/whats-wrong-with-this-wcf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the contract attribute from "ITry" to "test1.ITry" in the web.config.

```
<services> 
  <service name="test1.Try"> 
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Try" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="test1.ITry"/> 
  </service> 
</services>
```

Comment: +1 exactly - both the `name=` attribute of the `<service>` tag as well as the `contract=` attribute of the `<endpoint>` tag need to include the **fully qualified** names (interface/class name **including** all .NET namespaces!)

Comment: it now give this error When 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' is set to true in configuration, the endpoints are required to specify a relative address. If you are specifying a relative listen URI on the endpoint, then the address can be absolute. To fix this problem, specify a relative uri for endpoint 'http://localhost:8732/Try'.

Comment: when I run the website I got url like  http://localhost:1539/WCFService1/Service.svc?wsdl , what 
I want to call the login function and path parameters to it, what will be the url final shape please